# Getting iPhone location from a remote server

Tags: iphone, geolocation, nsurlconnection, multitasking

How does a remote server trigger an iPhone app to get current location? Apps that help locate your stolen/lost iPhone seem to be able to do this.

How is this possible? Does it use some kind of stealth push notification? Also, the phone app would have to update the remote server of its location, which means it will need to use the NSURLConnection features while backgrounded or terminated. Seems like magic to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That's not possible. It's always the device (iPhone) that reports its current location.

If **Find My iPhone** does it, it's probably running some special background application to report its location on a regular basis, or when the server requests it (through push notifications). But it's always the phone sending its location information.

Comment: Find my iPhone triggers the remote location check, it doesn't sends it on a regular basis to Apple.

Comment: True. Updated the answer to reflect that. Thanks!

Comment: Is this possible to do in the SDK? To trigger a remote check-in in the background?

Comment: Nope, its not possible with the current version. But you could file a feature request at bugreport.apple.com and tell them why you need this.

Answer (score 0):

An application on your phone can subscribe to a push service.  When the push is sent to the phone, it can send it's location to a server.

Comment: Only if the user opens the app when the Push Notification arrives. If its named "iStole an iPhone" or something like that, a thief most likely won't open it.